# Custom interceptor angularjs application using Parse service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

I am trying to implement an interceptor for my server responses (PARSE) with angularjs, I have seen this [project](https://github.com/lavinjj/angularjs-spinner) that uses the $httpProvider to register the interceptor.

since my service is not using $http service (is using PARSE), is there any way of implement my interceptor in the same clean way that the project sample?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?
I found this but it did not work
http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-loading-spinner-for-backbonejs

Comment: Write a wrapper to parse. And there you can have interceptor

Comment: I am already using this wrapper I forgot to say I am using this Parse wrapper. github.com/rafbgarcia/angular-parse-wrapper which is using promises BTW 
but I can't intercept it in a clean way

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Parse` service, I'd think of call `parse.com` API by using `$http` service only just we need to pass certain headers like `X-Parse-Application-Id` & `X-Parse-REST-API-Key` so that you could write your own interceptor that would have an control & watch over the request/response.

**Code**

```
$http({method : 'GET',
   url: 'https://api.parse.com/XXXXXXX', 
   headers: { 'X-Parse-Application-Id':'YYYYYYYYYYYY', 
   'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZ'}
})
.success(function(data){})
.error(function(err){});
```

Inspired from [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19865488/2435473)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I forgot to say I am using this Parse wrapper.
https://github.com/rafbgarcia/angular-parse-wrapper
which is using promises BTW

Comment: @MuhammadHassan can't we switch all those call using `$http`?

Comment: Well that's a good idea. but we will loose all the ease of Parse JS SDK
https://parse.com/docs/js/guide

and will have to use the very verbose and less object oriented REST SDK https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#queries 

Do you have any other ideas?
Can I intercept angular $q promises?

Comment: Can we use an idea like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797209/how-can-i-extend-q-promise-in-angularjs-with-a-succes-and-error I am not very expert with angular/$q so I can't customize it.

All I need is to intercept when $q promise is created and when its resolved/rejected

Comment: @MuhammadHassan surely we could implement by the way the answer has implemented.. but are you using `$q` while making call to parse.com