# What is wrong with this Angular-ui typeahead code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I made some minor modifications to the angular-ui typeahead example provided in http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Here is the original code inside the controller.

```
  $scope.getLocation = function(val) {
    return $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
      params: {
        address: val,
        sensor: false
      }
    }).then(function(res){
      var addresses = [];
      angular.forEach(res.data.results, function(item){
        addresses.push(item.formatted_address);
      });
      return addresses;
    });
  };
```

Here are the changes I made;

```
  $scope.getLocation = function(val) 
  {
    return $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', 
    {
      params: 
      {
        address: val,
        sensor: false
      }
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config)
    {
      var addresses = [];
      angular.forEach(data.results, function(item){
        addresses.push(item.formatted_address);
      });
      return addresses;
    });
  };
```

What is wrong with my code?  I did not get any error. The typeahead just did not work. I don't see any typeahead text as I type in the text inside the inputbox.

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a quiz site, can you let us know what the error is?

Comment: Sorry, I am still a newbie. I did not get any error. The typeahead just did not work. I don't see any typeahead text as I type in the text inside the inputbox.

Comment: Ok, that helps, you should edit the answer to let people know why you think your code is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.success()` method does **not** actually return a promise which is what the `typeahead` api expects.  The `.then()` method does return a promise.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16385350/238427) for more details about the difference between `.success()` and `.then()`.