# angular JS difference between these two ways of calling a web service method

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

Doesn't matter whether I am posting or deleting etc.. I would write this:

```
$http({
    method: ''
    url: '',
    data: '',
    headers: ''
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //whatever happens on success
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //whatever happens on failure
});
```

what is the difference between doing the above or doing this:

```
$http({
    method: ''
    url: '',
    data: '',
    headers: ''
}).then(function(response) {
    //success
},
    function(response) {
        //failed
};
```

Does one have advantages over the other? Did one come about later and there isn't much of a difference?
Just want to know the differences really and what people prefer to use and why.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular HttpPromise: difference between \`success\`/\`error\` methods and \`then\`'s arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385278/angular-httppromise-difference-between-success-error-methods-and-thens-a)

Answer (score 0):

From the [$http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> Returns a promise object with the standard then method and two http
>   specific methods: success and error. The then method takes two
>   arguments a success and an error callback which will be called with a
>   response object. The success and error methods take a single argument
>   - a function that will be called when the request succeeds or fails respectively. The arguments passed into these functions are
>   destructured representation of the response object passed into the
>   then method.

Which means that both examples you posted actually do the same, since `.success(function () { ... })` and `.error(function () { ... })` are just aliases of `.then(function () { ... })` and `.then(null, function () { ... }), respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `.then()` syntax came later, as everything was standardized on the $q API. `.success()` and `.error()` were probably left for backward-compatibility.

See the [Changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-33) for 0.10.6 where it says "the $xhr service was replaced with $http with promise based apis."