# Multiple loop with ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax code like following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var galname,URL,count,images,cur;
    $.ajax({
        url: "../Home/Gallery",
        success: function (data) {
            $(data).find("#galcontent p").each(function () {
                galname=$(this).html();
                URL = "../Home/Show?foldername=" + galname;
                alert(URL);
                $.ajax({
                    url: URL,
                    success: function (data) {
                    alert("find");
                    }
                });

            });
        }

    });

});
```

Actulaly i want the output like first alert URL, then goto next ajax loop and alert Find, then Next URL and so on. but in this loop its first alert all URL then goto next loop of ajax (only after the last each the second ajax loop is working.

Comment: because ajax is asynchronous.... but where is the loop

Comment: AJAX requests are asynchronous. The "loop body" is a *callback function* that will be executed a few milliseconds later, when the request completes. Unless your code relies on the order in which these requests complete, it should still work even if the alerts aren't in the order you expected.

Comment: @ling.s no, don't.  Just don't.

Comment: @Alnitak why? I always use that

Comment: Please define "not working".  Your statement of requirements is completely unclear.

Comment: @ling.s write code that doesn't rely on the order in which requests complete instead.

Comment: @ling.s because synchronous AJAX calls block the thread of execution, and lead to a bad user experience.

Comment: But the OP said it is working

Comment: @Alnitak: means first complete the each funtion, then only goto next ajax loop. i want to work the second ajax loop inside the each function

Comment: @ling.s there's "working", and then there's _"working properly"_

Comment: @shyama that's still totally unclear (despite the comment upvotes).  I only see _one_ `.each` loop, so where's this "second ajax loop" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the ajax calls to be executed sequentially, you need to make subsequent ajax calls as the success of the previous. You could achieve this a number of ways. One such is doing this recursively:

```
var galname,URL,count,images,cur,content;

function moreAjax(i) {
    if (i === content.length) return;
    else {
        galname=$(this).html();
        URL = "../Home/Show?foldername=" + galname;
        alert(URL);
        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            success: function(data) {
                alert("find");
                moreAjax(i + 1);   
            } 
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../Home/Gallery",
        success: function (data) {
            content = $(data).find("#galcontent p");
            moreAjax(0);
        }    
    });
});
```

I haven't tested this code out and JS isn't my native language, but I believe this approach should work.

Comment: it probably works, but it's not "clean" IMHO because it relies on too many variables in the outer scope.

Comment: That's fair. It would probably be better to declare a nested function as you did with loop(), thus keeping everything inside the $(document).ready. However, since he's not really working with the data from the inner ajax call, isn't it faster to use success() over then() (according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385278/angular-httppromise-difference-between-success-error-methods-and-thens-a)? I'm probably wrong since I'm not too familiar with javascript, but what is the advantage of using then()?

Comment: That article relates to angularjs, not jQuery.  AFAICR, jQuery these days implements `success:` just like `.then`.  I prefer to use `.then` because it's the modern "promise-based" method.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, your problem is that you wish to run the AJAX calls in serial rather than potentially in parallel.

Here, I'm using jQuery's `.then` method to (pseudo-)recursively call the inner `loop` function for each element in the array in turn:

```
function processData(data) {

    // get the URLs from the original AJAX download
    var URLs = $(data).find('#galcontent p').map(function() {
        return '../Home/Show?foldername=' + $(this).text(); // NB: not .html()
    }).get();

    // IIFE, processes one element from the array in turn
    (function loop() {
        var url = URLs.shift();
        if (url) {
            alert(url);
            $.ajax({ url: url }, success: function() {
                alert("find");
            }).then(loop);  // recurse here
        }
    })();
}
```

and then the above function can be passed as the `.then` callback to the first AJAX call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../Home/Gallery",
    }).then(processData);
});
```