# Angular $http service- success(), error(), then() methods

Tags: angularjs

When should I use `then()` method and what is the difference between `then(), success(), error()` methods ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular HttpPromise: difference between \`success\`/\`error\` methods and \`then\`'s arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385278/angular-httppromise-difference-between-success-error-methods-and-thens-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than the success un-wraps the response into four properties in callback, where as `then` does not. There is subtle difference between the two.

The `then` function returns a promise that is resolved by the return values for it's success and error callbacks.

The `success` and `error` too return a promise but it is always resolved with the return data of `$http` call itself. This is how the implementation for `success` in angular source looks like:

```
  promise.success = function(fn) {
    promise.then(function(response) {
      fn(response.data, response.status, response.headers, config);
    });
    return promise;
  };
```

To understand how it can affect our implementation, consider an example where we retrieve whether user exists based on email id. The http implementation below tries to retrieve the user based on userid.

```
$scope.userExists= $http.get('/users?email='test@abc.com'')
                        .then(function(response) {
                            if(response.data) return true;  //data is the data returned from server
                            else return false;
                         });
```

The promise assigned to `userExists` resolves to either true or false;

Whereas if we use `success`

```
$scope.userExists= $http.get('/users?email='test@abc.com'')
                        .success(function(data) {    //data is the response user data from server.
                            if(data) return true;  // These statements have no affect.
                            else return false;
                         });
```

The promise assigned to `userExists` resolves either a user object or `null`, because `success` returns the original `$http.get` promise.

Bottom line is use `then` if you want to do some type of promise chaining.

Comment: Thanks for the details explanation with real time issues :)

Answer (score 1):

`then()` method fires in both the success and failure cases. The `then()` method takes two arguments a success and an error callback which will be called with a response object.