# Angularjs $http.get doesn't call the callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I do the $http.get request as soon as my javascript loaded, it works fine in 90% percent of cases, however, sometimes it just dont call the success or error callback, I'm not sure if the request is actually sent or it just doesn't call the callback, it's weird because it works good in 90% of cases, and 100% if I run it on my own computer, if I put this onto remote server, this case will happen...

```
    $scope.load = function(){
    console.log("Sending request at "+Date());
    $http.get(requestUrl).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Loading Question Succeed");
        $scope.Content = data.Html;
        data = data.Data;
      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Loading Question Failed");
      });
};
$timeout($scope.load);
```

Comment: What do you see in the dev tools & network tab?

Comment: Have you looked at the network tab of your developer console to see if the request is actually being made? Could it be possible that your function that calls get is throwing an error before the get is ever made? Some code would be helpful.

Comment: I have console.log in both success and error callback, sometimes they just don't show up and there is no error message...

Comment: uhm, how does cache cause this problem?

Comment: Yes and and status code is 200

Comment: and I can also see the content, so it definitely succeed, but why it doesn't call the success callback

Comment: maybe the response is a page being redirected and that is causing an issue?

Comment: What is the benefit from using `$timeout` with no time param?  Are you trying to push this to the bottom of the Angular queue?  Why not just call `$scope.load()`?

Comment: Nope, it's just a node server using res.json({...}) stuff,

Comment: I use timeout because I thought it might be called when the function is not ready, so I put it to the bottom of queue

Comment: Can you call $http immediately after you load the page? I mean, usually people call it with a button click, that works fine, if you call it immediately after you load the page, do you need to be careful about something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider using a then() method rather than the traditional success\failure approach. Have a read up on promises or check out this post that explains the differences - 
[Angular HttpPromise: difference between `success`/`error` methods and `then`'s arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385278/angular-httppromise-difference-between-success-error-methods-and-thens-a)

In the post above take a look at one of the answers at the end which gives at example of using the then() method and also a catch()

Give it a try and see if it gives you more consistent results or if anything is ending up in the catch()

Comment: Great answer! Also, after I put {timeout: 7000} in the config argument, it works pretty well! Thank you