# Angular JS success works but not then, why?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, http

Please refer - http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/18728/

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller("mycontroller", function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    var url = "http://www.dummyurl.com";
    $http.get(url).success(
        function(response) {
              $scope.items = response;
    });
});
```

In Angular JS, I am making an ajax call using $http service. the data is getting populated using "success" callback, whereas it is not getting populated using "then" callback.
I have 2 questions -

1) What is the difference between success and then?
2) When to use "then", and when to "success"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385278/angular-httppromise-difference-between-success-error-methods-and-thens-a

Comment: Note that `success` is being deprecated per `$http` docs

Comment: Please confirm with a link which says that success is going to be deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the difference between success and then?

`then` resolves an object that represents your http response. That is to say, the callback of the `then` method take only one argument that has the following structure:

- `data – {string|Object}` – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
- `status – {number}` – HTTP status code of the response.
- `headers – {function([headerName])}` – Header getter function.
- `config – {Object}` – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
- `statusText – {string}` – HTTP status text of the response.

On the other hand, `success` is a shorthand function that will spread the different properties of the http response (except the statusText that is not very useful) into different arguments. Therefore the first argument of the `success` callback will contain only the response body (the property `response.data`) of the http response.

The following piece of code is taken from angular 1.4.5, and I was able to find it since angular 1.0.0:

```
promise.success = function(fn) {
   promise.then(function(response) {
      fn(response.data, response.status, response.headers, config);
   });
   return promise;
};
```

> When to use "then", and when to "success"?

For consistency with other promise libraries, I'll advise you to always use the standard `then` method. If you replace `$http.success` with `$http.then` be careful that what you got in the `response` object in the former, is equivalent to `response.data` in the latter:

```
$http.get(...).success(function (response) {
    return response;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
$http.get(...).then(function (response) {
    return response.data;
}
```

Comment: What does "directly resolves the body" mean in your answer

Comment: I meant that when you use `success`, the first argument of the callback is the http response body, whereas when you use `then`, the first argument is an object that represents the whole http response, with headers, statusCode, ... Will edit to make that more clear.

Comment: One query, I see that success return original promise, whereas then return new promise. and i am confused! what does it even mean, a js fiddle kinda explanation would be really helpful

Answer (score 2):

use success

```
$http.get(url)
  .success(function(response) {
    $scope.items = response;
  });
});
```

use then

```
$http.get(url)
  .then(function(data){
     $scope.items = data.data
   });
```

I think the different is the content of the passing parameter

Comment: I would swap names of parameters in success and then callbacks. You get response in 'then' function and data in 'success' function.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, I mainly use success when I am querying api or other databases. Then is mainly used when you request data from own database. This is my usage and what I saw others use.