# $http returning error response NULL on first call after launch (ionic) everytime, but after subsequent http post its ok

Tags: http, ionic-framework, null

Whenever I launch my app, and click on login on the first few tries, the login will attempt a POST http to the server. However $http always (everytime) returns NULL on first try. sometimes after several few tries still NULL if done fast. But subsequently, its all ok.

I dont get it, why is $http returning error response NULL initially ??

Here is my login controller doing the http post

Login Controller (LoginCtrl)
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/771194bc5815e4ccdf38b57d6158853f

```
var req = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: baseURL,
  data: postObject,
  //timeout: 5000
};
```

err is NULL here:

```
}).error(function(err) {
```

I dont know if it is CORS but I'ved got this set in config.xml

```
 <access origin="*" />
```

my config.xml
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b2df3a857338d14ec3fcd6dda776e212

Any ideas ?
Im using ionic 1.7.14
on device iOS 9.3.1

**UPDATE**

I'ved put the problem code here. can logout first to goto login screen. enter in anything in username/password field, click login once failed, second or third try will be success.

https://github.com/axilaris/ionic_null_http_problem

some troubleshooting so far: i noticed the http post request is called twice. not sure why.

UPDATED the code using $http.post.then but still has the same effect

```
 $http.post(baseURL, postObject).then(function successCallback(response)

 response has NULL data --> Object {data: null, status: 0, config: Object, statusText: ""}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a timeout in app.js that caused it. was set to 1 second which gives it it arbitrary success rate.

```
config.timeout = 1000;
```

Comment: Axil, did you try to wrap your code related to http request into $timeout() as I suggested before?

Comment: Can but i guess not really necessary for this bug

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to diagnose having the above details only.
However the problem could be that your handler (login function) is triggered before digest cycle finished updating $scope.data.username and $scope.data.password and for the first tries it sends empty values for those to the server and works fine later.
You can run Safari web inspector to see what is sent to the server to prove this.
The fix may depend on how your view/template is coded. Can you please share it? Or, ideally, create a working sample at http://play.ionic.io/

Another option to fix could be to try to wrap your code related to http request into

```
$timeout(function() { 
    // your code goes here
});
```

or, consider using .$applyAsync() (see the docs for details)
This might help to fix the problem

Comment: I'ved put the problem source here: https://github.com/axilaris/ionic_null_http_problem. it happens on web with "ionic serve" as well. one thing i noticed, the http post gets called twice. not sure why.

Comment: In the code you posted username and password are not passed to the server. See https://github.com/axilaris/ionic_null_http_problem/blob/master/www/js/controllers.js#L114. Besides this there is a problem with cross domain call. I got XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.veejansh.com/vurja/mobile.php. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8099' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: U would need cors chrome extension to get it working, username&password not required. Its a timeout issue

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting this inconsistent behavior as you are using the 'success' promise method instead of 'then' (note that use of the success method has now been [deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)).

The key differences between these two methods are:

> - then() - full power of the promise API but slightly more verbose
> - success() - doesn't return a promise but offeres slightly more convienient syntax

as highlighted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16385350/203371) answer.

Hence in your scenario, instead of using 'success':

```
var req = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: baseURL + 'session/login',
  data: postObject,
  //timeout: 5000
};

$http(req).success(function(resp) {...
```

use 'then' along with angular's [post](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) shortcut method (you don't have to use this shortcut method, but I think it makes the code more succinct) e.g.:

```
$http.post(baseURL + 'session/login', postObject).then(function successCallback(response) {
  // this callback will be called asynchronously
  // when the response is available
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  // called asynchronously if an error occurs
  // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

Using 'then' returns a promise resolved with a value returned from a callback, so it should give you a consistently valid result.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I updated the code using $http.post.then, its still the same behaviour. first few tries failed then successCallback. I'ved updated the code in github with your advise if you are keen to try it. Thanks.

Comment: I really did think it was due to the success method. When you say $http returns null what exactly do you mean? Do you mean that http returns a null promise? Is any of your console.log statements being output when you get your null result?

Comment: currently errorCallback(response). console.error('ERROR', response); retuns this ----->  ERROR, Object {data: null, status: 0, config: Object, statusText: ""}

Comment: previous code,  }).error(function(err) { the err variable returns null. ok i should change the title. my bad.

Comment: It could also be that your connection is not initialised when you start the app. Perhaps there is an issue with how your checking the connection (though it does look ok). Instead of using "if (window.cordova){..." you could try "if(window.Connection) {..." see [this](http://codepen.io/tahababa/pen/ZYYwEX) example.

Comment: Connection is OK. i tried with if(window.Connection), put it in separate branch testconnection_branch

Comment: Do you get different behaviour when you debug compared to when you just run the app?

Comment: same on ionic serve and on ios device. so its able to reproduce the same behaviour on web debugging.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109857/discussion-between-bensmith-and-axil).