# Angularjs - $http success vs then

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, angular-promise, angular-http

I want to ask about the difference about this method
My concern is difference between .then and .success, function and also .error
thanks.

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
   method: 'GET',
   url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
   // this callback will be called asynchronously
   // when the response is available
}, function errorCallback(response) {
   // called asynchronously if an error occurs
   // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

and

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
   method: 'GET',
   url: '/someUrl'
}).success(function successCallback(response) {
   // this callback will be called asynchronously
   // when the response is available
}).error( function(data) {
   // called asynchronously if an error occurs
   // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

Comment: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-promises%E2%80%93then-vs-success

Comment: Don't use success and error, use then and catch.

Comment: `.success` and `.error` are deprecated.

Comment: Find the documentation for promise here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises#t=201607280526409106492

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs - Difference between success and then](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385278/angular-httppromise-difference-between-success-error-methods-and-thens-a)

Comment: so can we add .error to catch error after using .then?

Comment: @vanculix no, you don't use `.error` with `.then`.  your own example in the question body shows the correct way to handle errors with `.then`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `.then()` and `.sucess()` are refer to promise it run asynchronously and wait for the response if it fullfied your request then `resolve` it otherwise `reject` it.

`.success` and `.error` are deprecated you can find more details on documentation