# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to change div automatic with `$scope.push`

but it still have problem with:

**Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**

My JSON and JAVASCRIPT codes:

**JSON**

```
{"records":[{"total":"156000"}]}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 $scope.plusCart = function() {
        $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : 'http://localhost/so-ku/www/server/menu/plus_cart',
            headers : { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' },
            data    : JSON.stringify({ rowid: $scope.currentItem.rowid, qty : $scope.currentItem.qty })
        }).success(function(data) {
            total_cart()
        });

    }
    function total_cart() {
    $http.get('http://localhost/so-ku/www/server/menu/total_cart').
        then(function(response){
            $scope.x = [];
            $scope.x = response.data.records;
            $scope.xtotal.push($scope.x.total);
    });
}
```

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="CartCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="tot in xtotal" style="padding-top: 10px;">
        Rp {{tot.total}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Note : I want to after submit plusCart , div automatically change the value with `$scope.push`

Thanks.

Comment: push works on array and $ scope is not a array. try on the veriable you defining and assigning value on it

Comment: what the code bro ?

Comment: Read [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your **JSON :**

```
{"records":[{"total":"156000"}]}
```

`response.data.records` already having an array `[{"total":"156000"}]`.So, there is no need to assign it again in an array.

**code correction :**

- Use only `$scope.x = response.data.records` instead of `$scope.x = []`
- Declare an array with name `$scope.xtotal`.

**Working Demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
  var jsonObj = {
  "records":[{"total":"156000"}]
  };
              
  $scope.xtotal = [];              
  $scope.x = jsonObj.records;
  $scope.xtotal.push($scope.x[0].total);
  console.log($scope.xtotal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in xtotal">
   {{item}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: $scope.xtotal is not automatic refresh after submit bro

Comment: @AzizalYunanP I did not understand what you want to say

Comment: i want to when i submit form then div refresh automatically change the value

Comment: @AzizalYunanP It will work with submit also. I just used mock json only for resolving the issue.

Comment: yeah done bro , 

i want ask a question once more , 

how push data with another page

example : 

header 

content 

button is in content area , but i want push data from header ??

Comment: @AzizalYunanP you have to use `$scope.broadcast` to pass the data from the parent to child controller.It will fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

as $scope.xtotal  is not defined, a array push is showing error there

try below

```
function total_cart() {
    $http.get('http://localhost/so-ku/www/server/menu/total_cart').
        then(function(response){
            $scope.xtotal = [];   ///define the veriable
            $scope.x = [];
            $scope.x = response.data.records;
            $scope.xtotal.push($scope.x.total);
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

$scope.x Is an array. because {"records":[{"total":"156000"}]}

If you want to assign all values from resonse.data.records you can simply do:

```
$scope.xtotal = response.data.records;
```

If you want to do manually, and yes you need to declare variable as an array:

```
$scope.xtotal = [];
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.x.length; i++) {
    var obj = $scope.x[i];
    // do your modification for an obj
    // and push to your $scope.xtotal
    $scope.xtotal.push(obj);
}
```

Comment: yes i know ,but when i submit post data , <div ng-repeat="tot in xtotal" > is not automatic refresh bro

Comment: I see, so after submitting the form, you are expecting total is updated in frontend? May be there are an error when submiting the form data. maybe you can add .error in your post method `$http({}).success(function(){}).error(function(){});`
And try to log something in error section
Also just my suggestion please use **.then** rather than **.success**
Please refer [here](http://www.dwmkerr.com/promises-in-angularjs-the-definitive-guide/#promisessuccesserrorthen) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627623/angularjs-http-success-vs-then)

Answer (score 0):

Because `$scope.x` (which is set to `response.data.records`) is already the array you want

```
$scope.xtotal.push($scope.x.total);
```

should just be

```
$scope.xtotal = $scope.x;
```

See plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fo1kffVaIUKe3DrRDODN?p=preview