# How To Integrate Error Handling With Controller and Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please see below the structure of my angular application:

I have a page called 'firm.html' which contains a button. Clicking this button executes the code below.

**Controller**

The controller calls a Service function. The `generationInProgress` variable is used in an ng-show to toggle the visibility of a loading gif on the HTML page

```
    $scope.generationInProgress = true;

    firmService.processFirm(firmRequest).then(function(response) {      

        window.location.href = "firm/process";          
        $scope.generationInProgress = false;

    });
```

**Firm Service**

This is a service that handles the Firm operations with the following function called above

```
this.processFirm = function(firmRequest) {      
    return httpService.put('firm/process', firmRequest);
};
```

**HTTP Service**

This is a service that handles all calls to the service. It is used by multiple services, including the firmService above. Here is the `put` method as called above

```
this.put = function(url, data) {

    return promise = $http.post(url, data).success(function(response) { 
        return response;
    }).error(function(response) {
        console.log("error");
    });

};
```

If a HTTP error code is returned by the server, obviously the `.error` function is executed. If I had a dedicated error page, I could just redirect to that page.

However, I need to display the error on the 'firm.html' page while also setting the `$scope.generationInProgress` back to false so that the loading gif is no longer displayed. None of the code that does this can be located within the httpService because it is a common service used by many different components.

I am unsure how to propagate the error back to the controller in order to accomplish this. Do I just put `return response;` in both the `.success` and `.error` and use an IF statement in the controller to test for the HTTP code? Is there an alternative method?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You have your answer below, but, seeing your code, I think you don´t totally understand promises; usually, you don´t define the success/error habndler if you are going to return it. So, your service should look like return $http.post(url, data); There is also some interesting stuff about this topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385278/angular-httppromise-difference-between-success-error-methods-and-thens-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.success` and `.error` methods have been deprecated. Instead, use the `.then` and `.catch` methods.

To chain a successful promise, `return` data to the `.then` method. To chain a rejected promise, `throw` the error response:

```
this.put = function(url, data) {

    //Use .then method
    return promise = $http.post(url, data).then(function(response) {
        //return to chain success 
        return response;
    //Use .catch method
    }).catch(function(response) {
        console.log("error");
        //throw to chain rejection
        throw response;
    });

};
```

From the Docs<sup>[1](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.14/docs/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)</sup>:

> ### Deprecation Notice
>
> The `$http` legacy promise methods `.success` and `.error` have been deprecated. Use the standard `.then` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle rejected state in controller, than present it as you like in html.

```
$scope.generationInProgress = true;
$scope.error = "";

firmService.processFirm(firmRequest).then(function(response) {      
    window.location.href = "firm/process";          
    $scope.generationInProgress = false;

}, function(err) {
    $scope.generationInProgress = false;
    $scope.error = "Your customized error message. Caused by: " + err;
});
```