# Make function in rootscope return in scope

Tags: angularjs, rootscope

I have made a rootscope function with a attribute. it is getting some data from a the db.

I want to use this rootscope function in a controller and put the data what i get in a variable.

```
$rootScope.get_option = function(option_name){
        $http.post("server/read.php",{'subject': "options", "args": option_name })
        .success(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            $rootScope.option_get_value = response;

        });

        if($rootScope.option_get_value){
            return $rootScope.option_get_value;
        }

    }
```

And this i what i have in the controller

```
    $scope.subscription.reduced_hourrate = $rootScope.get_option('verlaagd_tarief');
    console.log($scope.subscription.reduced_hourrate);
```

When i run the script, i see in the logs $rootScope function giving me correct value back. But the scope is giving me undefined data back.

Why is this happening? and someone help me of give me some tips?

Comment: Don't use `$http` `success()` method. Use `.then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$http` makes an asynchronus call. That means your `if` statement `if($rootScope.option_get_value) ...` is called before your http success function is resolved.

To make it work you can do it this way

```
$rootScope.get_option = function(option_name){
    return $http.post("server/read.php",{'subject': "options", "args": option_name })
}
```

Then inside your controller

```
$rootScope.get_option('verlaagd_tarief').success(function (response) {
     $rootScope.option_get_value = response;
});
```

**But I'm not sure this is the best way to pass data to a controller.** 
A common way is to use `services`. Without using `$rootScope`

Here is an example how to use of services to pass data to a controller.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

//declare a service that make the http calls
myApp.factory('myHttpService', function($scope, $http) {

   //return the public API
    return {
        //use a callback function to return
        //the result when the promise is resolved
        get_option : function(option_name, fct){
            $http.post("server/read.php",
                 {
                      "subject": "options", 
                      "args": option_name 
                 }
            ).then(function(result){
                fct(result) //calling the callback when the promise is resolved to return the result
            })
    }
});

// the controller using myHttpService
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myHttpService) {
   myHttpService.getOption('verlaagd_tarief', function(result){
       $scope.option_get_value = result
   })
});
```

Comment: Why you use Promise in first answer, but not in second?

Comment: in the second example I use a callback function that is called inside the `then` function  I just replace `.success` with `.then` which is the way I do usually. With `.then` you don't need to return `result.data` but only `result` see this post to understand the difference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385278/angular-httppromise-difference-between-success-error-methods-and-thens-a

Answer (score 1):

```
$rootScope.get_option = function(option_name){
    return $http.post("server/read.php",{'subject': "options", "args": option_name    })
    .success(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        if(response){
           return response;
        }
    });
}
```

When you call for the $http.post, the success return a while after the if line is called, that's why you are getting "undefined", because that the response didn't come back with data to fill $rootScope.option_get_value.
You are using ".success" (a promise inside $http: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http),
when you move your return into the promise it will launch only when the response is available.

In the console you see the full data from the response because that the console is working by reference, which means... when you click the log to open the obj, the return has already came back and it is refering the data to the console.

Comment: Your `return response` can not be used anywhere.