# external ip service returns 404

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm trying to retrieve the user's ip address from an external ip service. it works fine in the pc browser but it returns error 404 in the device. i've tried other external ip services but it ends up with the same error in the device. is there another way to get the device's external ip? how should i go about this?

here's my controller.js code:

```
$scope.findDeviceIP = function()
{
    $http.get("http://ipinfo.io/json")
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert('data is = ' +data);
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("error = " + data + "status = " + status);
    }); 
}

$scope.findDeviceIP();
```

and here's the error log:

```
error ip = {"data":"","status":404,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"http://ipinfo.io/json","headers":{"Accept":"application/json,text/plain,*/*"}},"statusText":"Not Found"}
```

Comment: this works fine in my ionic app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for it to work i placed the code inside a function called by a button.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use `.success` use `.then` for your callback. You can get more information about it [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385278/angular-httppromise-difference-between-success-error-methods-and-thens-a)

Try this

```html
<html>
<head>
<script Src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>

<script>
 var app=angular.module("myapp", []);
 app.controller("namesctrl", function($scope,$http){
        $scope.findDeviceIP = function(){
         $http.get("http://ipinfo.io/json")
            .then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('data is = ' +JSON.stringify(data));
            })
        }

        $scope.findDeviceIP();
 });

 
</script>


</head>
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="namesctrl">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the input. however the same error shows up.

Comment: in chrome inspector, i get a red circle with an x mark and beside it is this : ionic.bundle.js:25005 GET http://ipinfo.io/json