# window.localStorage.removeItem is not working in $http request

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I'm making a post request to my web service and when it is successful i'm trying to delete a token I've previously put in local storage like this:

```
$http.post("MyService/MyAction").success(function (res) {
                        if (res == true) {
                            window.localStorage.removeItem(myToken);
                            //window.localStorage.getItem(myToken) returns null in here.
                            window.location = baseURL + 'Login.aspx';
                        }
                    }).error(function () {
                        //some stuff
                    });
```

and right after that I'm redirecting to Login page on the site. now when i check the local storage if the tokens deleted right after `window.localStorage.removeItem(myToken)`, I see that it's deleted as `window.localStorage.getItem(myToken)` returns null.

But after I redirect with `window.location = baseURL + 'Login.aspx'` and check for the tokens with `window.localStorage.getItem(myToken)` in the Login.aspx page the token is there and not deleted.

**In Login.aspx**

```
window.localStorage.getItem(myToken)
//in here the token is returned where it's suppose to be deleted.
```

At first I thought I'm adding the token again in somewhere between the redirection to Login.aspx, but when i use $.ajax to send the request and delete token it works. So is there something about angularjs that $http is not doing what I can do with $.ajax.

Comment: Could it be redirecting before it gets a chance to delete?

Comment: window.localStorage.removeItem(myToken);
                            //window.localStorage.getItem(myToken) returns null in here.
                            window.location = baseURL + 'Login.aspx';   i'm redirecting after deleting it. How could that be?

Comment: Javascript is asynchronous though, so it doesn't matter what order it is in, Javascript will complete whatever actions it can as soon as possible regardless of how they were called. So if deleting the token takes longer than redirecting, it could redirect before deleting the token

Comment: I kinda thought that could be happening but how can prevent it? I understand $http doesn't support asynchronous=false.

Comment: to see if this is the case, set a timeout before redirecting and then see if it deletes

Comment: I've set timeout for 5 sec. like this:` $timeout(function () { window.location = '<mysite.Login.aspx>' }, 5000);` but it's deleting the token before redirecting. (BTW I haven't looked at your solution yet.)

Comment: it is or isn't deleting?

Comment: It is deleting the token.

Comment: ok, then my solution should work

Comment: What sets the token? are you sure it's not just being reset somewhere?

Comment: @KevinB the token is not set between `window.localStorage.removeItem(myToken)` and in the login page `window.localStorage.getItem(myToken)` . It works with $.ajax though with same structure, maybe @CumminUp07 right about asynchronous thing.

Comment: Please try `localStorage.removeItem('your key')`

Answer (score 0):

You could chain the promises to make sure it gets completed

```
$http.post("MyService/MyAction").then(function (res) {
     if (res == true) {
         window.localStorage.removeItem(myToken);
         //window.localStorage.getItem(myToken) returns null in here.     
     }
})
.then(
    window.location = baseURL + 'Login.aspx';
)
.error(function () {
    //some stuff
});
```

Comment: Ok this doesn't work but thanks to you i went in the right direction. I needed to run `window.localStorage.removeItem(myToken)` and `window.location = 'Login.aspx'` sequentially. And i find how to do it in this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23805864/6287784)

Comment: ok, i'm glad you found the answer, i've updated my answer to reflect how to fix it