# Fetching particular json key from controller AngularJS 1

Tags: angularjs, json, api, get

Hi I am new in AngularJS and trying to fetch and show json key data separately to console window. I can able to fetch entire json data , but unable to fetch datas within a particular node. Where am I going wrong ?

**Service.js**

```
app.service("AppService", function($http) {
    return {
       network: [],
       getAllService: function(network){

        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://99.126.4.6:3200/app/json/allDatas',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} 

        })
                .then(function(data) {
                    return data;
                })
    }
    }
});
```

**Controller :-**

```
app.controller('getController', ['$scope','$http','AppService','$localStorage', function ($scope,$http,AppService,$localStorage) {


            $scope.load = AppService.getAllService();
            $scope.load.then(function(data) {
            $scope.getAllData = data; 
            $scope.getId = data.ID;
            $scope.getName = data.Name;
            $scope.getDescription = data.Description;
            console.log($scope.getId + $scope.getName + $scope.getDescription);
            })

}]);
```

*When I console `getAllData` I can see entire json response.But unable to fetch inner keys.*

**JSON response:-**

```
Data
Array(1)
0
:
{$id: "1", ID: 1, Name: "APP", Description: "Something", Segments: Array(3)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing the old syntax with a new one: [`.success` vs. `.then`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385278/angular-httppromise-difference-between-success-error-methods-and-thens-a)

`.then()` returns an [Http Promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-returns) which wraps your response in an object. To pull out your data, you need to access `.data` first.

Fix this line from:

```
.then(function(data) {
  return data;
})
```

to

```
.then(function(data) {
  return data.data;
})
```

Comment: Now I am getting this response in my console. `(22) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] {$id: "1", ID: 1, Name: "App", Description: "Some description", Segments: Array(3)}` . So does the data get stored on my controller over here `$scope.getId = data.ID;
            $scope.getName = data.Name;
            $scope.getDescription = data.Description;`

Comment: @WhoAmI I think you are also [store it in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49730593/8495123) (_for whatever reason_), try `data.data[0];` as a workaround

Comment: Thank you for your help . I am getting the infos .

Comment: Hey! the array contains many objects and I want to display the whole. [0] will show only the first object.

Comment: @WhoAmI then use `data.data` and change your other logic to accept the array instead. For example `$scope.getAllData` can be used in `ng-repeat="data in getAlldata"` and then you can pull out the properties with `{{data.ID}}`, etc. (At this point it's beyond the scope of your question, fix it yourself, or ask a new one)

Comment: Sure , Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

data is an array, so access it's value by index

```
    $scope.load = AppService.getAllService();
    $scope.load.then(function(data) {
    angular.forEach(data, function(value) {
       console.log(value.ID+"   "+value.name++"   "+value.escription);
    });
    })
```

Comment: Ok , this worked too. Thank You. I want to show every objects contained in the array.

Comment: Loop the data and console it
angular.forEach(data, function(value) {
  console.log(value.ID+"   "+value.name++"   "+value.escription);
});

Comment: Throwing errors: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` and `[ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ng/areq?p0=getController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined`

Comment: Edited, please check it now

Comment: It's still incorrect. Though I maked the correction. `$scope.load = AppService.getAllService();
   $scope.load.then(function(data) {
    
   angular.forEach(data, function(value) {
    $scope.getAllData = data; 
   console.log(value.ID +value.Name + value.Description);
   });
   });` It's working fine for me . Thanks for the help.