# Error in AngularJS-Bootstrap TypeAhead: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, servlets, typeahead

I am getting the below error while trying to implement AngularJS Typeahead from AngularUI-Bootstrap:
(I am simply calling a servlet which returns the results in JSON format)

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js:3553:24
    at wrappedCallback (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js:10930:81)
    at wrappedCallback (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js:10930:81)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js:11016:26
    at Scope.$eval (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js:11936:28)
    at Scope.$digest (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js:11762:31)
    at Scope.$apply (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js:12042:24)
```

**HTML**

```
<h4>Users from local service</h4>
    <pre>Model: {{userList | json}}</pre>
    <input type="text" ng-model="userList" placeholder="Users loaded from local database" 
    typeahead="username for username in fetchUsers($viewValue)" 
    typeahead-loading="loadingUsers" class="form-control">
    <i ng-show="loadingUsers" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.fetchUsers = function(val) {
        console.log("Entered fetchUsers function");
        $http.get("http://localhost:8080/TestWeb/users", {
            params : {
                username : val
            }
        }).then(function(res) {
            var users = [];
            angular.forEach(res.data, function(item) {
                users.push(item.UserName);
            });
            return users;
        });
    };
```

**Servlet**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        UserUtil userUtil = new UserUtil();
        List userList = userUtil.fetchUsers();
        Iterator userIterator = userList.iterator();

        JSONArray users = new JSONArray();


        while(userIterator.hasNext()) {
            UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails)userIterator.next();

            JSONObject jo =  new JSONObject();
            jo.put("UserID", userDetails.getUserId());
            jo.put("UserName", userDetails.getUserName());
            jo.put("UserDescription", userDetails.getDescription());

            users.add(jo);
        }

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().write(users.toString());


    }
```

**Response from the servlet**
[image]

I have referred to the below questions:

- [AngularUI-Bootstrap's Typeahead Can't Read `length` Property of `undefined`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525184/angularui-bootstraps-typeahead-cant-read-length-property-of-undefined)
- [typeahead angular ui - cannot read property 'length' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595235/typeahead-angular-ui-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined)

However, still I am unable to figure out the resolution. Is there any issue with the response from the servlet itself? Or is it something else?

Comment: can you give us an example output from your backend? it looks like typehead is expecting an array here

Comment: @maurycy Added the snapshot of the response in the question.

Comment: Cool, that looks fine, can you log the `users` right before returning it? it should be an array of strings

Comment: Yes, it shows me the array like this: users= ["Test user2", "Test user3", "Test user4", "Test user5", "Test user6"]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

after second look at code I've noticed what's wrong, you have to return $http promise here, notice `return` before $http

```
$scope.fetchUsers = function(val) {
        console.log("Entered fetchUsers function");
        return $http.get("http://localhost:8080/TestWeb/users", {
            params : {
                username : val
            }
        }).then(function(res) {
            var users = [];
            angular.forEach(res.data, function(item) {
                users.push(item.UserName);
            });
            return users;
        });
    };
```

Comment: My bad, worked as soon as I added "return" :) You saved the day!

Comment: easy to overlook, have a nice day :)