# Angular typeahead : watch for dataset change

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs, typeahead.js

I am using [Siyfion's typeahead directive](https://github.com/Siyfion/angular-typeahead) in my project.

What I do in my controller is something like this :

```
$http({method: 'GET', 'url': CONFIG.SOMEURL})                             
    .success(function(data, status, headers , config){                       
    if(status==200)                                                          
    {                                                                        
        $scope.objects = data;                                                
        for(i=0; i < $scope.objects.length; i++){                             
            $scope.allObjects.push($scope.objects[i].name);  
        }                                                                    
        console.log($scope.allObjects);                                       

$scope.dataSet = {                                                           
    name : 'objs',                                                         
    local : $scope.allObjects                                                                                                             
};
```

I get an array of 'objects' as json from `django` view. But the problem is in my  HTML template:

```
<input type="text" class='sfTypeahead' datasets='dataSet' ng-model='testname' />
```

Since the `dataSet` initially is empty while the async call is being made I get an error :

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Is there a way if I can look for changes in `dataSet` or `datasets` so that as soon as the array `allObjects` gets populated,The DOM gets refreshed maybe ?

Can anyone suggest what could be done here

Comment: Just use http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead instead which works nativelly with promises as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15930592/1418796

Comment: Would it support bs3 ? I am currently using bs3.

Comment: Yes, it should work with BS3 without issues

Comment: Thanks for the link. Will give that a read :)

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource. Thanks for the resource.Is there a good read which can help me understand how promises work with directives ? I mean how should I write my directive so that It takes functions which return promises, as its input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full disclosure: I'm the author of the aforementioned directive.

Essentially, you are trying to do all the prefetching in Angular itself, when Typeahead.js & Bloodhound are designed specifically to do this for you. Take a good look at https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/ and pay particular attention to the Bloodhound suggestion engine.

Perhaps of some use:

- https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#remote
- https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#remote
- https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#prefetch

**NOTE:** The version of the directive you were using (9 months ago) didn't support updating the dataset local variable, but it now does, so you *could* do it that way, if you liked.