# Using promises with directives in angularjs

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs

This is related to my previous question : 
[Angular typeahead : watch for dataset change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655053/angular-typeahead-watch-for-dataset-change)

I am using [Siyfion's typeahead directive](https://github.com/Siyfion/angular-typeahead) for my project since its a few lines of code simple to understand (for beginners like me ).

Now I have a django backend server which returns JSON objects which I would like to use for autocomplete.

Right now my controller looks like this :

```
$scope.getGuests = function (guestValue) {
  return $http.jsonp('http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?callback=JSON_CALLBACK &filter=US&q=' + guestValue)
    .then(function (response) {
      return limitToFilter(response.data, 15);
    });
};
```

My markup :

```
<input type="text" class='sfTypeahead' datasets='getGuests($viewValue)' ngModel='testname' />
```

Now this obviously doesn't work because my widget doesn't load until it has `datasets` ready completely.
Is there a way where I can write  directives such that I can use them like how its shown above ?

Answer (score 1):

Check if this works:

```
$scope.getGuests = function (guestValue) {
    var promise = $q.defer();
    $http.jsonp('http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?
    callback=JSON_CALLBACK &filter=US&q=' + guestValue)
    .success(function (response) {
        promise.resolve(limitToFilter(response, 15));
    });
    return promise.promise;
};
```