# What's the correct expression for the Angular-UI Typeahead directive?

Tags: json, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, directive, typeahead

I'm trying to get the name to show for each element, but I'm getting the same name for each element. Here's the code:

View:

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-controller="MenuItemEditTypeaheadCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="selectedItem" typeahead="menuItem.name for name in menuItems | limitTo:3" class="typeahead">
</li>
```

JSON:

```
[{name: "Soda", price: "2.99"}, {name: "Chips", price: "0.99"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text=[{name: "Soda", price: "2.99"}, {name: "Chips", price: "0.99"}];
obj=JSON.parse(text);
```

Print obj using loop

obj[0].name will print "Soda"
obj[1].name will print "Chips"

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't think I adequately conveyed that my question was in regards to the "expression" formula I needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer:

"menuItem.name for menuItem in menuItems | limitTo:5 | filter:{name:$viewValue}"

Answer (score 0):

try like below

**Script:**

```
 $scope.menuItems = [{name: "Soda", price: "2.99"}, {name: "Chips", price: "0.99"}];
```

**HTML:**

```
 <li class="list-group-item" ng-controller="MenuItemEditTypeaheadCtrl">
     <input type="text" ng-model="selectedItem" typeahead="menuItem.name for menuItem in menuItems | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:3 " class="typeahead">
 </li>
```

**Note:** $viewValue corresponds to a value entered by a user

And if you want to tie your angular typeahead with a server then refer this below link

[How to tie angular-ui's typeahead with a server via $http for server side optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930339/how-to-tie-angular-uis-typeahead-with-a-server-via-http-for-server-side-optimi)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Correct me if I'm wrong, though:

The limitTo filter should be last, because if angular processes the filters in order, subsequently passing a shortened array, limiting the array before it filtered would leave good results out of the list because it was *arbitrarily* removed before checking whether it matched.

Comment: you are absolutely correct...I updated my answer and thanks for correcting my mistake